# persistent map buffer (glBufferStorage with GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT) performance

Tags: c++, opengl

Continuing to learn modern GL I recently came across persistent map buffers. The first results however have been more than disappointing. Instead of some improvement or even comparable results compared with glBufferData the performance is hardly 1/3 of it.
Now I am wondering if it is plain wrong implementation or whatever I could have missed. Interestingly it also slows down all other rendering tasks which still use glBufferData massively and it very much seems that glFenceSync is causing the entire delay.

Here is what I do:

```
GLbitfield PersistentBufferFlags = GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT;
if (bDrawTileBuffers)
{
    glBufferStorage(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_SIZE, 0, PersistentBufferFlags);
    DrawTilePMB = (float*)glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,VBO_SIZE, PersistentBufferFlags);
    bDrawTileBuffers=true;
}
```

called once to create the buffer.

```
void CleanBuffer(GLsync &SyncBuffer)
{
    glDeleteSync( SyncBuffer ); 
}

void LockBuffer(GLsync &SyncBuffer)
{
    SyncBuffer = glFenceSync( GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0 );
}

void WaitBuffer(GLsync &SyncBuffer)
{
    if( SyncBuffer )
    {
        GLbitfield WaitFlags=0;
        while( 1 )  
        {
            GLenum WaitReturn = glClientWaitSync( SyncBuffer, WaitFlags, 1 );
            if (WaitReturn == GL_ALREADY_SIGNALED || WaitReturn == GL_CONDITION_SATISFIED)
                return; 
            WaitFlags=GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT; //Failsafe, triple buffering should avoid this ever being set (expensive).
        }
    }
}
```

For buffer handling.

```
GLuint IndexOffset = DrawTileBufferRange[DrawTileIndex].Begin;
if (DrawTileBufferRange[DrawTileIndex].Sync)
{
    WaitBuffer(DrawTileBufferRange[DrawTileIndex].Sync);
    CleanBuffer(DrawTileBufferRange[DrawTileIndex].Sync);
}
DrawTilePMB[IndexOffset+0] = RFX2*Z*(X - Frame->FX2);
DrawTilePMB[IndexOffset+1] = RFY2*Z*(Y - Frame->FY2);
DrawTilePMB[IndexOffset+2] = Z;
DrawTilePMB[IndexOffset+3] = (U)*TexInfo[0].UMult;
DrawTilePMB[IndexOffset+4] = (V)*TexInfo[0].VMult;
```

To feed in the data,

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, Stride, (void*)(DrawTileIndex*(TotalSize*sizeof(float))));
glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, Stride, (void*)(DrawTileIndex*(TotalSize*sizeof(float))+VertOffset));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertsize / FloatsPerVertex);

LockBuffer(DrawTileBufferRange[DrawTileIndex].Sync);
DrawTileBufferRange[DrawTileIndex].Begin = DrawTileIndex * TotalSize;
DrawTileIndex = (DrawTileIndex + 1) % 3;
```

to finally draw it.
Since I am using triple buffering there is NEVER any wait. Of course, now that I have the buffer I could (and probably will) reduce the number of draw calls by buffering more than one set of data to optimize it even more, but I'd expect at least the same performance as with glBufferData, indeed even somewhat more since it is supposed to read driver overhead from what I read- or is that I HAVE TO "collect data" to reduce draw calls to really benefit from it? On the other hand this seems to make all this effort with it and the entire function pretty useless to me.
I also read that GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT might have a negative effect and manually flush with glFlushMappedBufferRange is supposed to better, but this doesn't seem to be the origin of the problem.

Any enlightenment is very appreciated :)

Comment: "Since I am using triple buffering there is NEVER any wait" I fail to see any triple buffering in your code. Also, how much stuff are you actually drawing?

Comment: It's a single buffer broken into 3 pieces, therefor the offset with the DrawTileIndex. Maybe that's also a possible reason, but my first attempts with 3 single buffers didn't show any difference so far- could try again though since I made quite some progress in between. How much is drawn varies a lot, it can be a single draw with 12 verts, but also a few hundreds of these, I think up to 3000 verts, depending on situation.